# AppInstall remote event is called multiple times

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers, apps-development

When developing provider hosted apps and testing in SharePoint Online, I've noticed that my AppInstalled remote event is often triggered 4 times when installing the app in site content. Here is an except from a log:

```
[07:47:38] ProcessEvent: AppInstalled
[07:47:54] ProcessEvent: AppInstalled
[07:48:04] ProcessEvent: AppInstalled
[07:48:10] ProcessEvent: AppInstalled
```

I suspect SPO thinks the installation somehow failed and therefore trying attempting to install it again. How can I stop this from happening? I tried using `clientContext.RequestTimeout = Timeout.Infinite` without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have yet to find any good solution to this problem. [Some](http://akhileshnirapure.blogspot.in/2014/06/sharepoint-2013-app-handling-app.html) suggest intercepting events and cancel/halt them until the first call is finished. While I was able to use this technique while developing, it causes other problems though, especially with communicating back to SharePoint if the app was properly installed or not. Thus I do not find it an acceptable solution for production.

I decided to remedy the situation by moving the (time expensive) provisioning code from the AppInstall event into a button on the App's page. The user will first have to install the app, then open the app and manually click the button to complete the installation. From a user experience point of view this is not as good, but it seems to be the most proper way to do this for now.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that SP will retry 4 times if it fails to install/upgrade/uninstall.
Have you checked to see if there are any errors being thrown from your Remote Event? There could be errors in generating ClientContext? A snippet of the code will help to diagnose?

If you do have errors, ensure you set the `ErrorMessage` and `Status` of the `SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();` before returning to SharePoint.

You can also propagate errors to the App Details page using the following code:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.LogCustomRemoteAppError(ctx, productId, messageToLog);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: No, it does not have to do with error being thrown. (It happens during normal execution. Another irritating situation is when debugging the code: Suppose I have a breakpoint, the debugger will sometimes trigger this breakoint several times, jumping back and forth between two or more threads being debugged at the same time.)

Comment: It might be a bit easier to diagnose with a code snippet to show us? Because what you are describing is exactly what would happen as a result of an exception...

Comment: I understand, but the code in question is hundreds, perhaps thousands of lines so it's not possible. A lot of it is based on PnP for best practice, and exceptions are handled. I'm pretty sure the problem is not an exception, because I can follow the code flow both using the debugger and my logs, and there I can see that new calls are made even though old calls are still running.

Comment: Being "thousands of lines of code", could the request be timing out and so SharePoint tries to call the service endpoint again? Maybe try to increase the `executionTimeout` value in the Web.Config of your Remote Web?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but after setting executionTimeout to 300, I could still see in the logs that a new call was made only 30 seconds after the initial one.